# ValueError: _isdir: path too long for Windows

Tags: python

I am working on flask app while I run flask app. It show an error **"ValueError: _isdir: path too long for Windows"**. I don't know why it show this type of error.

you can see in image below:

```py
from docx import Document

def cleanhtml(raw_html):
  cleanr = re.compile('<.*?>')
  cleantext = re.sub(cleanr, '', raw_html)
  return cleantext


response = requests.get(url)
if response.status_code == 200:
    print(Document(response.text),"++++++++++++++++++++")
    full_text = cleanhtml(Document(response.text).summary())
```

*Error*

[image]

Comment: What is ```pkg_file``` like?

Comment: @ewong I'm using docx module